# I Check some Tutorial of Location Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, ddms

It is possible to check location and with address using emulator? with out putting longitude and latitude in DDMS? because I see some tutorial and I try it not working in my emulator or maybe i miss something ..

please give some advice .
I'm kinda newbie in android development .

Thanks in Advance I Really appreciate ..

Comment: what tutorial are you following?

Comment: i forgot the site but i download a snippets of it and run it on my emulator.